# Ubuntu 20.04 constantly displays 0% battery

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery

I'm having an issue where Ubuntu on my HP Spectre laptop seems to believe my battery is constantly at 0%, even if I've kept it plugged in for a long time. I know this is an issue with Ubuntu 20.04 because when I log into the Windows partition of my dual-booted laptop, it accurately shows that the battery power is 100%.

When I check the battery status using `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`, I get the following output:

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               HP
  model:                Primary
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Wed 01 Jun 2022 11:58:08 AM PDT (2 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         0 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             13.039 V
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

Any suggestions at all on how to fix this? I'm unable to use my computer without keeping it plugged in constantly now, so it's super annoying.

Comment: I don't know 100% but you can start with maybe a suggestion here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-batteryestimate.html.en  I am thinking that it might need a recalibration see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377196/why-always-my-battery-power-percentage-shows-0